# How can i set Scheduler of Ibm on the first Monday of the week?

Tags: websphere, scheduler

How can i set Scheduler of Ibm on the first Monday of the week? If i set DayOfMonth 1-7 and DayOfTheWeek 2 together receive an error. Is not good simbol as 2#1

Answer (score 0):

The error is consistent with the documentation
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-zos/8.5.5?topic=SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/scheduler/UserCalendar.html
which states, "The day of week and day of month terms cannot be specified at the same time. One must be a '?' and the other a term."

Regarding your question, you asked about the "first Monday of the week".  Did you mean first Monday of the month?
Here is an example of Monday of every week at 8am:

```
0 0 8 ? * MON
```

where the Scheduler cron terms are
second minute hourOfDay DayOfMonth Month DayOfWeek

If you want only the first Monday of the month, the Scheduler CRON doesn't have a way to do it.

An easy, but inefficient, solution would be to use the syntax for every Monday and have your task logic return immediately and skip itself if not a first Monday.

You also have the option of supplying your own UserCalendar implementation to implement customized scheduling:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/api/v1/content/SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/scheduler/TaskInfo.html#setUserCalendar(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)